# Sort array of EmberJS objects by property

Tags: arrays, sorting, object, properties, ember.js

I noticed this on the EmberJS website under Filtering:

> Another common task to perform on an Enumerable is to take the
>   Enumerable as input, and return an Array after ***sorting*** or filtering it
>   based on some criteria.

Imagine I have an array of Ember objects, how do I go about sorting them by property?

```
App.DemoArray = Ember.ArrayController.create({
    content:[
        Ember.Object.create({name:'Joe', Age:29}),
        Ember.Object.create({name:'Jim', Age:53}),
        Ember.Object.create({name:'Jack', Age:12})
    ]
})
```

What if I wanted to sort the above by age? Thanks for your help!

EDIT:
I found this in the sproutcore documentation but it doesn't seem to work with Ember:

> You can sort an Enumerable based on the value of some property or list
>   of properties using sortProperty. If you pass in multiple properties,
>   SproutCore will sort items with the same value for the first property
>   by the value of the second parameter, and so on.

Section 3.8 on this page: http://guides.sproutcore20.com/enumerables.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[As described here](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.SortableMixin.html) you can now sort your ArrayController.

The way you do it is provide extra properties on your ArrayController (pasted from link above):

```js
songs = [
  {trackNumber: 4, title: 'Ob-La-Di, Ob-La-Da'},
  {trackNumber: 2, title: 'Back in the U.S.S.R.'},
  {trackNumber: 3, title: 'Glass Onion'},
];

songsController = Ember.ArrayController.create({
  content: songs,
  sortProperties: ['trackNumber'],
  sortAscending: true
});

songsController.get('firstObject');  // {trackNumber: 2, title: 'Back in the U.S.S.R.'}
songsController.addObject({trackNumber: 1, title: 'Dear Prudence'});
songsController.get('firstObject');  // {trackNumber: 1, title: 'Dear Prudence'}
```

Answer (score 16):

Ember `MutableArray` has a `sortBy` method:

https://emberjs.com/api/ember/release/classes/MutableArray

Answer (score 11):

EDIT: The below solution seems to only apply to numeric values. However this link will give advice on how to handle alpha-numeric, dates, etc: http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/arraysort2.shtml

Nevermind, I figured it out. You can do it with Javascripts built in sort method:

```
//To sort ASC
var sorted = content.sort(function(a,b) {
    return a.get('propertyYouWantToSortBy') - b.get('propertyYouWantToSortBy');
});

//To sort DESC
var sorted = content.sort(function(a,b) {
    return b.get('propertyYouWantToSortBy') - a.get('propertyYouWantToSortBy');
});
```

Answer (score 4):

in case anybody comes across this, the updated way to sort in ember is

```
 Ember.computed.sort('nameOfArrayToSort', sortDefinition)
```

sortDefinition may be an array of strings

```
 ['mainSortProperty:asc', 'secondarySortProp:desc', ...]
```

or a comparator function

docs here: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.computed.html#method_sort

Answer (score 3):

As discussed in https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/335 sorting is not implemented anymore in the core `ember.js` package.

Comment: It seems to be back as SortableMixin. http://docs.edge.emberjs.com/symbols/Ember.SortableMixin.html