# Sort content of ArrayController

Tags: arrays, sorting, ember.js

I have a `Ember.ArrayController` that has an unsorted content.

I want to know if its possible to sort the content of an ArrayController without using a new property.

I could of course create a new property:

```
App.MyArrayController = Em.ArrayController.extend({
  mySortMethod: function(obj1, obj2) {
    // some code here
  },
  updateSortedContent: function() {
    var content = this.get('content');
    if (content) {
      var sortedContent = content.copy();
      sortedContent.sort(this.mySortMethod);
      this.set('sortedContent', sortedContent);
    }
  }.observes('content')
});
```

But I hope there is a better way that does not duplicates the content.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sort array of EmberJS objects by property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9041505/sort-array-of-emberjs-objects-by-property)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

**UPDATE**

The latest version of Ember actually has sorting built in. `ArrayController` now includes the `Ember.SortableMixin` which will engage if you specify `sortProperties` (Array) and optionally `sortAscending` (Boolean).

Note: with the new SortableMixin, you still need to refer to `arrangedContent` to get the sorted version. The model itself will be left untouched. (Thanks to Jonathan Tran)

```
App.userController = Ember.ArrayController.create({
  content: [],
  sortProperties: ['age'],
  sortAscending: false
})
```

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

The correct way to do this is to use the `arrangedContent` property of ArrayProxy. This property is designed to be overridden to provide a sorted or filtered version of the content array.

```
App.userController = Ember.ArrayController.create({
  content: [],
  sort: "desc",
  arrangedContent: Ember.computed("content", function() {
    var content, sortedContent;
    content = this.get("content");
    if (content) {
      if (this.get("sort") === "desc") {
        this.set("sort", "asc");
        sortedContent = content.sort(function(a, b) {
          return a.get("age") - b.get("age");
        });
      } else {
        this.set("sort", "desc");
        sortedContent = content.sort(function(a, b) {
          return b.get("age") - a.get("age");
        });
      }
      return sortedContent;
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }).cacheable()
});
```

Comment: Defining a sortProperty sorts by default. Can this is changed to adapt sorting only when a user request is registered(through a dropdown or something) ?

Comment: You define the default sort properties and ascending to be whatever is "normal" to your content. Then you make a little action that changes those two properties via buttons or drop-downs and magic happens. I have a reSort method on the controller that sets the sort property (I use only one) to what the button sends as an argument. And if the property is the same as the one already set it interprets that as an indication to reverse the order to descending. https://gist.github.com/3744939

Comment: Note: with the new SortableMixin, you still need to refer to `arrangedContent` to get the sorted version. This tripped me up at first.

Comment: @JonathanTran Could you please explain, what do you mean by 'you still need to refer to arrangedContent'? Where do I need to refer it?

Comment: @SatA In your template, or wherever you need the sorted version, don't use `content`.  That is the original model array and won't be sorted.

Answer (score 2):

You have to manually sort arrays, including any array controller's content, in Ember. You could always replace `content` with your sorted array instead of keeping both arrays.

**Update**

Here is an example of what I think you're looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/ud3323/yjs8D/

**Update #2**

Updated this example to use the new view context changes. https://gist.github.com/2494968

**Handlebars**

```html
<script type="text/x-handlebars" >
Will Display and Sort by Age (after 2 sec)<br/><br/>

{{#each App.userController}}
    {{#view App.RecordView}}
        {{name}} - {{age}}
    {{/view}}
{{/each}}
</script>
```

**JavaScript**

```js
App = Ember.Application.create({
    ready: function() {
        Ember.run.later(this, function() {
            Ember.run.later(this, function() {
                App.get('userController').set('content', [
                   Ember.Object.create({ name:"Jeff", age:24 }),
                   Ember.Object.create({ name:"Sue", age:32 }),
                   Ember.Object.create({ name:"Jim", age:12 })
               ]);
      }, 2000);
        Ember.run.later(this, function() {
            // Make the controller's content sort again in reverse this time
            App.userController.notifyPropertyChange('content');
        }, 4000);
    }
});

App.userController = Ember.ArrayController.create({
    content: [],

    contentDidChange: Ember.observer(function(userCtr, prop) {
        if(!Ember.empty(this.get('content'))) {
            console.log('about to begin sort');
            this.sortContent();
        }

        this._super();
    }, 'content'),

    sort:"desc",

    sortContent:function() {
        var content = this.get("content"), sortedContent;

        if (this.get("sort") == "desc") {
            this.set("sort", "asc");
            sortedContent = content.sort( function(a,b){
                return a.get("age") - b.get("age");
            });
        } else {
            this.set("sort","desc");
            sortedContent = content.sort( function(a,b){
                return b.get("age") - a.get("age");
            });
        }

        this.set("content",sortedContent);
    }
});

App.RecordView = Ember.View.extend({});
```

​

Comment: yep, but I do not know where to replace it, because if the 'content' observer replace the content, the callback will be sent again, and again, and again,...

Comment: it works! I already tried that but I called `this._super()` before sorting the content so it did not work. Anyway, thank you

Comment: Yeah that's an undocumented little Ember gotcha. You have to call `_super()` at the end because `contentDidChange` defined in `Ember.ArrayProxy` will add in the observers on the `content` property that `Ember.ArrayProxy` needs. So the trick is that you want to change the `content` before you add those observers or you'll hit the infinite loop problem it sounds like you're already experienced ;)