# Looping through model in unrelated template in ember

Tags: ember.js

I apologize if I am missing some key concepts here. I am brand new to ember and don't feel like I fundamentally "get it" yet.

In the app I'm working on, there is is a sidebar which needs to display all of the user's albums regardless of the route the user is on.

Inside of this sidebar template I want to do something like this where I render an album template for each album.

```
{{#each App.AlbumsController}}
  {{render "albums.album_link" this}
{{/each}}
```

edit: Importantly, I  do not want album to be the model for the application controller because I want to render at least one more model in this same sidebar and be able to switch between them.

Based off of advice at : [Sort content of ArrayController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10498969/sort-content-of-arraycontroller) (not sure whats going on with the {{#view App.RecordView}}. Is that important? )

I have no 'albums' route as this sidebar is the only place the albums index will ever be displayed and it doesn't need its own view.

```
App.AlbumsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  content: [],
  sortProperties: ['title'],
  sortAscending: false 
});
```

When this is evaluated it gets an error in the console: Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: The value that #each loops over must be an Array. You passed App.AlbumsController

I think my problem  lies in the fact that I do not understand what  the "content" attribute on an arrayController does and I'm probably not setting this up correctly to load the album objects into the controller

I've created a bin with my failed attempt at looping the albums in the sidebar template: http://jsbin.com/nufusa/9/edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get this to come out right, instead of:

```
App.AlbumsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  content: [],
  sortProperties: ['title'],
  sortAscending: false 
});
```

it was important to create instead of extend the ArrayController in a single line and then set it's properties seperately.

```
App.albumsController = Ember.ArrayController.create();

App.albumsController.set('sortProperties', ['title']);
App.albumsController.set('content', App.Album.FIXTURES);
```

working js.bin: http://jsbin.com/nufusa/10/edit

Answer (score 1):

If the sidebar content will be the same across all routes, the easiest way would be to define the albums as the application route model:

```
# Route
var App.ApplicationRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    # Retrieve your albums, depending on where you store that data
  }
})

# Outernmost template (application.hbs)
<div class="sidebar">
  {{#each}}
    {{render "albums.album_link" this}}
  {{/each}}
</div>
<div class="main">
  {{ outlet }}
</div>
```

If different routes will have different sidebars, use outlets to display the sidebar. You can target the sidebar outlet like this:

```
var App.SomeRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  renderTemplate: function() {
    this.render();
    this.render('sidebar/something', {
      into: 'application',
      outlet: 'sidebar'
    });
  }
});
```

You can find more information about rendering templates in outlets in the ember guide: http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/rendering-a-template/

Comment: I realize now I wasn't specific enough and updated the question. Eventually I want to have more than one model being rendered in that sidebar so I want to give them each their own controller and loop through each of the controllers in the sidebar template

Comment: Do you mean more than one different model, or several albums? If it's an array of several albums – you set this as model. If you use Ember.Data, it will look like this: ``this.store.find('album')`` -> will retrieve all albums, ``this.store.find('album', 1)`` -> will retrieve one album (with id: 1)

Comment: Ultimately there will be multiple different models displayed in this template which is why I would not like to set a specific model for the application itself

I really appreciate you taking the time to respond though! It forced me to be clearer in my question.