# How to keep an array controller's content sorted according to a function

Tags: ember.js

I'm looking at [this section](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ArrayController.html#property_sortFunction) of the docs, and it seems like I should be able to do the following:

```
//controllers/some-controller.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  sortFunction: function(a, b) {
    debugger;
    // some sort code
  }
});
```

to sort my controller, but I can't. What am I missing?

Comment: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.SortableMixin.html#property_sortFunction ?

Comment: "Note: with the new SortableMixin, you still need to refer to arrangedContent to get the sorted version. The model itself will be left untouched."
Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10498969/sort-content-of-arraycontroller

Answer (score 0):

I didn't realize `sortFunction` operates on the parameters passed into `sortProperties`. So, you have to define a `sortProperties` array, then you can use the `sortFunction` as a custom sort function:

```
//controllers/some-controller.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  sortProperties: ['id'],
  sortFunction: function(a, b) {
    return +a > +b ? 1 : -1;
  }
});
```

This will keep the controller sorted, and you can simply refer to `some-controller` in e.g. an `{{#each}}` loop. You don't need to reference `arrangedContent`.