# Ember group and order

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have the following two models:

```
App.City = DS.Model.extend({
    cityId: DS.attr('number'),
    name: DS.attr()
});

App.Country = DS.Model.extend({
    countryId: DS.attr('number'),
    name: DS.attr()
});
```

And my fixtures for city looks like this:

```
App.City.FIXTURES = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Dallas', cityId: 1 },
    { id: 2, name: 'Waco', cityId: 2 },
    { id: 3, name: 'Waco', cityId: 2 },
    { id: 4, name: 'Nashville', cityId: 3 },
    { id: 5, name: 'Norfolk', cityId: 4 }
];
```

My list looks like this:

- Dallas (delete)
- Waco (delete)
- Waco (delete)
- Nashville (delete)
- Norfolk (delete)

I want my list to be grouped by cityId, and then sorted by name:

- 1x Dallas (delete)
- 1x Nashville (delete)
- 1x Norfolk (delete)
- 2x Waco (delete)

When the user clicks delete next to Waco, the 2x turns into 1x, and deletes one of the Waco records from the store. If the user clicks delete again, Waco is removed from the list, and the last Waco record is removed from the store.

I have two different lists on the same view, and want the same behaviour for each of the lists (grouped and sorted).

Here's the code I have now: http://jsfiddle.net/cLNJj/1/

Comment: Can you maybe explain what you're having trouble with? What specifically do you not understand how to do?

Comment: I updated my question now. I've written what my current data looks like, and what I want it to look like. Basically I want multiple items to be grouped together, if they have an identical cityId, and the two lists sorted alphabetically. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is that JSBin updated with what you want to do: http://jsfiddle.net/qv8f8/.

Basically it uses a computed property to get only the uniq models. You can see that here:

```
uniqCities: function() {
    var cities = this.get('content');
    var names = cities.mapBy('name');
    var uniqCities = cities.filter(function(item, idx, array) {
        if (names.contains(item.get('name'))) {
            names.removeObject(item.get('name'));
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    });
    return uniqCities;
}.property('content'),
```

And then in the ObjectController it has a count property which checks how many times the current model is repeated in it's parent's content:

```
count: function() {
    var cities = this.get('parentController.content'), 
        citiesWithThisName = cities.filterBy('name', this.get('name'));
    return citiesWithThisName.get('length');
}.property('content'),
```

Feel free to ask any questions.

---

Updated for your questions in the comments:

I've updated the JSBin to change the count and properly remove the deleted items. The major/only change here was using `model.length` for the uniqCities computed property. I'm not actually sure why that was needed as I'm pretty sure I haven't needed to do that in my own code, but it could be a caveat of the Fixture adapter. [Check out the JS Bin here.](http://jsfiddle.net/GowGuy47/E9vy4/).

As for sorting I'd [check out this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9068293/1159410) to another SO question. That should lead you in the right direction.

Ahh and for making it a bit more reusable I would suggest having two different array controllers which are used for that route. That way you can make a base abstract subclass of ArrayController which can have the uniqueCities/Countries method on it and then use that for the two new controllers. I'll let you figure that out on your own though. :)

Comment: A couple of questions: 1) How do I update the count value, when I delete one of the Waco items? When I click delete the first time, it should say 1x, and then I delete again, it should disappear from the list. 2) How do I sort the list by the cityname? 3) Can I make this functionality a bit more reusable, so I can use it for both models (City and Country)?